# How to find the integral $\sin^2\sqrt2x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help finding the integral of $\sin^2\sqrt2x$

I started to integrate it using integration by parts:

$u=sin^2\sqrt2x$     and     $dv=dx$

$\int u \,{\rm d}v = uv - \int v\,{\rm d}u$

But when I start to integrate it it just keeps geting more and more complicated

Comment: I have tried to integrate it by parts, with u= \sin^2\sqrt2x and dv= dx, but i cant get it right

Comment: Outline: Let our integral be $I$. One integration by parts will get you $I=f(x)+k \int \cos^2(\sqrt{2}x)\,dx$. Rewrite the $\cos^2(\sqrt{2}x)$ as $1-\sin^2(\sqrt{x})$ and you will get a linear equation for $I$.

Comment: The double angle formula for cosine is probably the easiest method.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\int \sin^2(\sqrt{2}x)\,{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{2}\int 1 - \cos(2\sqrt{2}x)\, {\rm d}x.$$

Comment: The thing is I'm just starting to learn to integrate and hacve to do it by parts

Comment: Then call $u = \sin^2(\sqrt{2}x),{\rm d}v = {\rm d}x$ and throw it all in the formula $\int u \,{\rm d}v = uv - \int v\,{\rm d}u$. But using trigonometric identities is the easiest way.

Comment: That's what I have been doing, but every time it keeps getting more and more complex

Comment: It is easier if you add your work in the question (as an edit), this way people will have an easier time finding out where it is going wrong.

Comment: Should I add more information?, I'm sorry it's the first time I post a question here

Comment: The more you add, more people can help you. If you don't add anything we can't give hints and explanations at an appropriate level.

Comment: @IvoTerek That's the wrong way. If you let $dv = dx$ You'll get $x$ in the new integral

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$u = \sin(\sqrt{2}x), \quad dv = \sin (\sqrt{2}x)\,dx \\ 
\implies du = \sqrt{2}\cos (\sqrt{2}x) \,dx, \quad v = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos (\sqrt{2}x)$$

Then

$$ \int \sin^2 \big( \sqrt{2}x \big)\,dx = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin \big(\sqrt{2} x \big)\cos \big( \sqrt{2} x \big) + \int \cos^2 \big( \sqrt{2} x \big)\,dx$$

Notice $$\cos^2 \big( \sqrt{2} x \big) = 1 - \sin^2 \big( \sqrt{2} x \big)$$